# How reliable is checkdnsrr (for email domain validation)?

Tags: php, dns

I am wondering whether there is a realistic chance of a false negative when utilising checkdnsrr to check the domain part of a provided email address? I want to check this coming from a registration form to reduce the amount of mistypes on the client side.

```
$hostCheck = checkdnsrr("test.org", "MX");
```

Is checkdnsrr just "pretty reliable" or is there no practical chance of missing an actually existing domain? Because then I would omit such a check. I would appreciate an explanation on the WHYs of the reliability of the whole process. I have researched DNS (some), but I am not certain whether things like servers being temporarily offline or something else might have a measurable impact here.

Comment: verify an email address by sending an email to that address and get a response back (click here to validate your email address)- that's the best way. considering the billions of registered domains, i could type any random string.com and likely get a valid domain.

Comment: And make them type it twice.

Comment: i copy and paste when i'm asked to do it twice, so its not really that useful

Comment: you can get completely different MX hostnames than the domain listed in the email address, e.g. anything using Google's hosted mail service would have a .google.com MX, but be 'someone@example.com'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this isn't reliable.  dns isn't reliable in general.  It's best-effort.  It can also take a long time when an invalid domain is provided, so you need to consider a potential DOS of your system if someone hammers your script with a lot of invalid/offline domains.

In (little known) fact, domains don't even need to have an MX record for mail to be delivered.  Mail delivery is supposed to fall back to using the A record for the host specified.  That may not really happen much these days, but in theory..